# Resize HTML canvas with .scale()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to resize a `<canvas>` with an image already drawn, but I'm misunderstanding how to use the `canvas.scale()` method because it doesn't shrink...

Code:

```
ImageRender.prototype.resizeTo = function () {

    var canvas          = $('#myCanvas')[0];
    var ctx             = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //current image
    var currImg         = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //
    var tempCanvas      = $('canvas')[0];
    var tempCtx         = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
    tempCtx.putImageData(currImg, 0, 0)

    //
    ctx.scale(0.5, 0.5);

    //redraw
    ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);
  };
```

What am I overlooking?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a code snippet that can reproduce this issue. Also, see [`ctx.scale()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale).

Comment: please replace **ctx**.scale(0.5, 0.5) with **canvas**.scale(0.5, 0.5);

Comment: You can use `getImageData/putImageData` to crop, but `context.scale` only affects subsequent drawings, so `putImageData` won't scale for you because (1) it was created before scaling, and (2) its not actually a drawing -- it's simply replacing pixel-by-pixel back on the canvas. ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can scale your canvas with content by "bouncing" the content off a temporary canvas while you resize the original canvas. This save+redraw process is necessary because canvas content is automatically cleared when you resize the canvas width or height.

Example code:

[image]

```js
var myCanvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=myCanvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var tempCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var tctx=tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/Dog-With-Cute-Cat.jpg";
function start(){
  myCanvas.width=img.width;
  myCanvas.height=img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  resizeTo(myCanvas,0.50);
}

function resizeTo(canvas,pct){
  var cw=canvas.width;
  var ch=canvas.height;
  tempCanvas.width=cw;
  tempCanvas.height=ch;
  tctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
  canvas.width*=pct;
  canvas.height*=pct;
  var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas,0,0,cw,ch,0,0,cw*pct,ch*pct);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>Canvas resized to 50%</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<h4>Img with original image</h4>
<img src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/Dog-With-Cute-Cat.jpg'>
```

Comment: So .scale() doesn't work? What's that function for then...?

Comment: Worked great for me scaling images and pdf views.  +1

Comment: @Hasen `.scale()` just applies a transform draw operations. ie. doing `ctx.scale(3, 0.5)` and then drawing with `ctx.rect(0, 0, 100, 100)` will actually draw a rect that is 300, 50 in size. The scale method is a simplified version of `setTransform()` in this regard, check out the docs for a better explanation.

Comment: @Magikarp Based on your description that would seem to be 'scaling' rather than transforming, but it clearly didn't work like that for the op.

Comment: @Hasen The way you described it indicated to me that you haven't read the documentation for the `scale` or `setTransform` methods, which include examples showing how they're used. `scale` only sets height/width transform while `setTransform` uses a 3x3 matrix is capable of effects like shear/perspective. They both function similarly in what they actually do and are identical in how they're used (they affect size of content that is drawn after calling). MDN could improve on this by adding a note about `drawImage`'s exception to this, but otherwise this is also a misunderstanding of their usage.

Comment: rl;dr, OP wasn't using `scale` properly, and it wouldn't have applied to `drawImage` if it had been used properly, so there were two separate problems at play here and identifying the latter was the crux.

Answer (score 7):

Simpler way would be using the extra parameters of `drawImage()`. 4th and 5th parameters let you set the final width and height.

Also, you can paint an image (or a canvas) directly, without the need of getting the ImageData.

Also(2), I think you may want to resize the canvas too (just use its width and height properties)

https://jsfiddle.net/mezeL06o/

Comment: This is good, but based on his previous question, I think the questioner instead wants to resize the existing canvas content rather than scaling the img.

Comment: I did that too in the jsfiddle