# Scale objects after loadFromJson

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Let's say I'm working on a 1000x1000 px fabric canvas. I add an 200x200px image right in the middle (top: 400, left: 400), then save my canvas as json. (the bag on these pictures is a background image, don't mind it)

[image]

I create another canvas, which is smaller. If I load my json, image will still be 200x200px, and 400px from top and left, therefore getting out of my canvas.

[image]

How can I make sure that, once loaded in a smaller/bigger canvas, my objects will scale accordingly ?

Comment: have you tried the method described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34867213/7393478)?

Comment: @Kaddath unfortunately this is for html5 canvas, I'm trying on a fabric.js canvas

Comment: hum, i don't know these, maybe you could edit your post to add the code, so that it's more obvious to the others

Answer (score -2):

Work out the new canvas dimensions as a percentage of the original canvas then set the scale on each of the items in the callback of loadJSON.

As in your example if original canvas was 400x400, new one is 200x200 then scale is 0.5. Apply that to each object in the callback of loadJSON and to its coordinates (top, left etc etc).